# Find the range of values that fullfill a condition in a column from another colum using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is the dataframe where each column either has a prefix of `c` or `s`.

`c` represents a class(either yes or no) and `s` represents the score related to that class.

```
     cAGR cCON cEXT cNEU cOPN  sAGR  sCON  sEXT  sNEU  sOPN
2157    y    y    y    n    y  4.17  3.67  4.33  2.00  4.40
2422    y    n    y    n    y  3.95  3.25  4.20  2.60  5.00
2741    y    n    n    n    y  4.00  3.00  2.75  2.50  4.75
2884    y    y    y    n    y  3.55  3.95  3.75  2.05  3.80
4830    n    n    n    y    y  3.05  3.05  3.40  2.80  4.35
4932    y    n    n    y    y  3.85  3.10  2.75  3.65  3.80
5611    y    n    n    n    y  3.65  3.25  2.80  1.60  4.15
5743    n    y    n    y    n  3.35  4.25  3.30  2.80  3.50
6360    y    y    n    y    y  3.85  4.35  3.20  3.60  4.80
6822    y    y    y    n    y  4.50  3.50  4.13  1.43  4.13
```

I am trying to get the min and max scores in a column(`sAGR`) based on whether it is `y` or `n` in the same class(`cAGR`) so that I can know what score is the min or max score to be in either a positive class or a negative class i.e. the range of these values.

For example in the code below I get the max and min value of the value `y` and `n` in `cAGR`.

With this I can say that `cAGR` is `y` when the value in `sAGR` is in the range of `3.55` to `4.5` and that `cAGR` is `n` when the value in `sAGR` is in the range of `3.05` to `3.35`.

The code below is sufficient but it is really repetitive and I am wondering if there is a better way to do it?

```
>>> df['sAGR'].where(df['cAGR'] == 'y').max()
4.5
>>> df['sAGR'].where(df['cAGR'] == 'y').min()
3.55
>>> df['sAGR'].where(df['cAGR'] == 'n').min()
3.05
>>> df['sAGR'].where(df['cAGR'] == 'n').max()
3.35
```

Dictionary of data:

```
{'cAGR': {2157: 'y',
  2422: 'y',
  2741: 'y',
  2884: 'y',
  4830: 'n',
  4932: 'y',
  5611: 'y',
  5743: 'n',
  6360: 'y',
  6822: 'y'},
 'cCON': {2157: 'y',
  2422: 'n',
  2741: 'n',
  2884: 'y',
  4830: 'n',
  4932: 'n',
  5611: 'n',
  5743: 'y',
  6360: 'y',
  6822: 'y'},
 'cEXT': {2157: 'y',
  2422: 'y',
  2741: 'n',
  2884: 'y',
  4830: 'n',
  4932: 'n',
  5611: 'n',
  5743: 'n',
  6360: 'n',
  6822: 'y'},
 'cNEU': {2157: 'n',
  2422: 'n',
  2741: 'n',
  2884: 'n',
  4830: 'y',
  4932: 'y',
  5611: 'n',
  5743: 'y',
  6360: 'y',
  6822: 'n'},
 'cOPN': {2157: 'y',
  2422: 'y',
  2741: 'y',
  2884: 'y',
  4830: 'y',
  4932: 'y',
  5611: 'y',
  5743: 'n',
  6360: 'y',
  6822: 'y'},
 'sAGR': {2157: 4.17,
  2422: 3.95,
  2741: 4.0,
  2884: 3.55,
  4830: 3.05,
  4932: 3.85,
  5611: 3.65,
  5743: 3.35,
  6360: 3.85,
  6822: 4.5},
 'sCON': {2157: 3.67,
  2422: 3.25,
  2741: 3.0,
  2884: 3.95,
  4830: 3.05,
  4932: 3.1,
  5611: 3.25,
  5743: 4.25,
  6360: 4.35,
  6822: 3.5},
 'sEXT': {2157: 4.33,
  2422: 4.2,
  2741: 2.75,
  2884: 3.75,
  4830: 3.4,
  4932: 2.75,
  5611: 2.8,
  5743: 3.3,
  6360: 3.2,
  6822: 4.13},
 'sNEU': {2157: 2.0,
  2422: 2.6,
  2741: 2.5,
  2884: 2.05,
  4830: 2.8,
  4932: 3.65,
  5611: 1.6,
  5743: 2.8,
  6360: 3.6,
  6822: 1.43},
 'sOPN': {2157: 4.4,
  2422: 5.0,
  2741: 4.75,
  2884: 3.8,
  4830: 4.35,
  4932: 3.8,
  5611: 4.15,
  5743: 3.5,
  6360: 4.8,
  6822: 4.13}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('cAGR')['sAGR'].agg(['min','max'])
```

Output:

```
       min   max
cAGR            
n     3.05  3.35
y     3.55  4.50
```

---

**Bonus** if you want to do so with other suffixes, try `pd.wide_to_long`:

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), i='index',
                stubnames=['c','s'], j='cat',
                suffix='.*' )
   .groupby(['cat','c'])['s'].agg(['min','max'])
)
```

Output:

```
        min   max
cat c            
AGR n  3.05  3.35
    y  3.55  4.50
CON n  3.00  3.25
    y  3.50  4.35
EXT n  2.75  3.40
    y  3.75  4.33
NEU n  1.43  2.60
    y  2.80  3.65
OPN n  3.50  3.50
    y  3.80  5.00
```

Comment: Thanks the bonus answer was what I was looking for!